# My .onSucceed (okhttp) throws "Service must only be used fromm FX Application Thread"

Tags: java, http, exception, javafx, okhttp

I wrote an Interceptor which catches the 401 HTTP Status and then calls a method which sends a RefreshToken to the server to get a new AccessToken. For some reason it doesn't work although in the same class I have got a second function which does almost the same and works completely fine.

Am i missing out on something?
Thanks in advance.

Function where error occures:

```
public void RefreshToken(){
    try{
      if(db==null){
        db=Database.newInstance();
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
      System.out.println("Error in while getting new Database");
    }
    Service<String> t=db.GetAccessToken();


    t.setOnSucceeded(e -> { //Error thrown here
      Database.ACCESSTOKEN=t.getValue();
    });
    t.setOnFailed(e -> {
      System.out.println("Error with HTTP GET new Token");
    });
  }
```

Almost the same Function:

```
private void Login(String username, String password) {
    Service<BothTokens> t=db.Login(new Credentials(username,password));
    t.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
      Database.REFRESHTOKEN=t.getValue().getRefreshToken();
      Database.ACCESSTOKEN=t.getValue().getAccessToken();
      openMainFXML();
      closeWindow();
    });
    t.setOnFailed(e -> {
      new ServiceExceptionHandler<>(t).handleServiceWithRetryOrClose((Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow(),
          "Error beim Login",
          t.getException().getMessage(), (Exception) t.getException());
    });
  }
```

Interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient OK_HTTP_CLIENT = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        if(originalResponse.code()==401){
            try{
                Login_Controller login=Login_Controller.newInstance();
                login.RefreshToken();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Error getting new Token");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return originalResponse;
    }).build();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service must only be used from the FX Application Thread
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.checkThread(Service.java:906)
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.setOnSucceeded(Service.java:409)
  at pkgController.Login_Controller.RefreshToken(Login_Controller.java:106)
  at pkgServices.statics.StaticServerObjects.lambda$static$0(StaticServerObjects.java:19)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
  at pkgServices.buildings.GetBuildings$1.call(GetBuildings.java:32)
  at pkgServices.buildings.GetBuildings$1.call(GetBuildings.java:25)
  at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Service.java:725)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Service.java:724)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: Exception occured in GetBuildings with code: 401
  at pkgServices.buildings.GetBuildings$1.call(GetBuildings.java:40)
  at pkgServices.buildings.GetBuildings$1.call(GetBuildings.java:25)
  at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Service.java:725)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Service.java:724)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception occured in GetBuildings with code: 401
  at pkgServices.buildings.GetBuildings$1.call(GetBuildings.java:37)
  ... 9 more
```

Comment: java naming conventions, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest javafx AsyncTask [Libray](https://github.com/victorlaerte/jfx-asynctask?source=post_page-----26689f3cd8fa----------------------)
and prepare your requests as below:

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    private UIController controller;

    public Example(UIController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    void onPreExecute() {
        //PREPARE GUI, SHOW PROGRESS OR SOMETHING....
        this.controller.updateProgressLabel("Starting Download")
    }

    @Override
    String doInBackground() {
        //THIS METHOD WORKING IN BACKGROUND HERE YOU SOULD IMPLEMENT CODE OF HTTP REQUEST AND RETURN RESULT OF REQUEST FOR EXAMPLE OBJECT OR JSON STRING
      return new String();
    }

    @Override
    void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //HERE YOU CAN GET YOUR DATA FROM REQUEST AND SET RESULT ON GUI
        this.controller.updateProgressLabel(result);
    }

    @Override
    void progressCallback(Object... params) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function was running in a different thread than the FXML-Controller and I had to write

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {....} )
```

Comment: you might want to flash out the `{...}` part a bit, to make it easier for future readers :)